# Program crashes when play video with QWebView

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt5.1

Here is the code

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWebView view;
    QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("./plugins");
    view.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
    // crash here
    view.load(QUrl("http://hon.qq.com/act/20140320video/Aluna.html"));
    // OK to show youtube
    //view.load(QUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE"));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

It crashes when play video on hon.qq.com, but works well playing video on Youtube.

Comment: Additional info: Windows 8.1 64bit OS, Qt5.1.0, Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Comment: It would be useful to see the backtrace of the crash.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x5265c3b2 in q5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd.

Comment: NPSWF32.dll!5265c3b2()  
  [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for NPSWF32.dll] 
  NPSWF32.dll!527e3697()  
  NPSWF32.dll!527e764f()  
  Qt5WebKitd.dll!0fedc315()  
  Qt5WebKitd.dll!0fedd0c0()  
  Qt5WebKitd.dll!0fef2bbc()  
  Qt5WebKitd.dll!0f8e944f()  
  Qt5WebKitd.dll!0f843269()  
  Qt5WebKitd.dll!0f842454()  
  Qt5WebKitd.dll!0f8422e9()  
  Qt5WebKitd.dll!0f845481()

Comment: I didn't find any useful information from call stack...It seems NPSWF32.dll crashes when handling data from website